# Selenium IDE: Select random from dropdown

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide, xpath-2.0

I using Selenium IDE for my automated tests.

And right now I have to select a random post from a dropdown.

How do I do that using xpath?

Answer (score 0):

Try following solution :

Command: Select

Target : element Locator eg : id = card

Value : index=1

Hope it will work for you.